# Monodroid Linking Sdk Assemblies causing SIGSEGV in Mono Library

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin, mvvmcross

I have C# Android code that works fine when using either Shared Runtime (Mono) or Linking Sdk Assemblies, but when both are present, it stops working.  I can build with No linking, without using shared runtime and it runs flawlessly, but when I am trying to package for deployment (Sdk Linking and No Shared Runtime) I get a SIGSEGV:

```
03-22 08:23:56.486 E/mono-rt ( 2526): Stacktrace:
03-22 08:23:56.486 E/mono-rt ( 2526): 
03-22 08:23:56.496 E/mono-rt ( 2526):   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
03-22 08:23:56.496 E/mono-rt ( 2526):   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption_internal (intptr,System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel,System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName,object,byte[],int,int&) <IL 0x0002a, 0xffffffff>
03-22 08:23:56.496 E/mono-rt ( 2526):   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.SetSocketOption (System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionLevel,System.Net.Sockets.SocketOptionName,object) <IL 0x000c2, 0x004cf>
03-22 08:23:56.496 E/mono-rt ( 2526):   at Keiser.Plugin.Socket.NetSocket.CreateListeningSocket () [0x00041] in d:\Development\Keiser.MPM.Screen\Keiser.Plugin.Socket.Droid\NetSocket.cs:73
03-22 08:23:56.496 E/mono-rt ( 2526):   at Keiser.Plugin.Socket.NetSocket.StartListener (System.AsyncCallback) [0x00012] in d:\Development\Keiser.MPM.Screen\Keiser.Plugin.Socket.Droid\NetSocket.cs:92
The program 'Mono' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
```

The last method in my code is this:

```
    protected virtual void CreateListeningSocket()
    {
        lock (Locker)
        {
            _socket = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Dgram, ProtocolType.Udp);
            IPEndPoint ipEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, _port);
            _socket.Bind(ipEndPoint);
            _socket.SetSocketOption(SocketOptionLevel.IP, SocketOptionName.AddMembership, new MulticastOption(IPAddress.Parse(_ipAddress)));
            _endPointSender = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0);
        }
    }
```

Is there any way for me to solve this?  I've tried refactoring using UDPClient, but it gives the same error on the line where I call the JoinMulticastGroup on the UDPClient object.  Is this an error inside of the monodroid assembly?

** Note: This code is inside a MvvmCross plugin which is reference by the Core PCL for the project, which is itself reference by the Android project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I know how to reproduce it, sent it to Xamarin. It happens when calling JoinMulticastGroup and also starting another socket operation in background. https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=22183 Reproducible in Mono 5.4. Workaround is to JoinMulticastGroup before performing any other socket operations.

Answer (score 4):

I still don't know WHY this is happening, but I have found a solution.

In the Android Solution properties, under the Android Options Tab, with the Release configuration selected, I used SDK Assemblies Only linking, and added System to the Skip linking assemblies option, and disabled "Use Shared Runtime".

This makes the APK file a little larger, but not by much (10.1Mb vs 9.8Mb in my case).

Comment: If you know exactly which functions got stripped out by the linker, you can also add an linker script file for this particular functions. E.g. see: http://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/5804/#Comment_5804

Comment: It's difficult.  I have the same functions in other parts which worked just fine, so the problem is somewhere deeper than the "SetSocketOption_internal" function.  I attempted to exclude System.Net from linking, and that didn't resolve the issue, only once I excluded the System.dll did it work.